# Find odd pair in string of integers using python

Tags: python, string

How do I write a function that takes in a string and returns the same string with every pair of odd numbers separated with a dash.

Assume that all characters in the string are numeric.

i.e. "456793" -> "4567-9-3"

Comment: Pretty sure 5 is an odd number too, so why isn't the expected output "45-67-9-3"?

Comment: @blhsing 6 is not odd, so 5 and 6 are not a pair of odd digits, no?

Comment: @Amadan Thanks. Makes sense now.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
s = "456793"
print(''.join([a + ('-' if b and int(a) * int(b) % 2 else '') for a, b in zip_longest(s, s[1:])]))
```

This outputs:

```
4567-9-3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
re.sub(r'(?<=[13579])(?=[13579])', '-', "456793")
# => '4567-9-3'
```

"Find all places where an odd digit is before and an odd digit is after, and insert a dash."